# Using RenderPartial(): the css files are not loaded

Tags: symfony1, partial

I have this action below at miembros/actions/actions.class.php:

```
public function executeFoo(sfWebRequest $request){

     return $this->renderPartial('foo');

}
```

and in *miembros/templates* i have _*foo.php*

When i execute it, the css files i have at *frontend/config/view.yml* are
not loaded. I have also tried using in _*foo.php*:

```
<?php use_stylesheet('my_css_file.css') ?>
```

but it doesn't work either...

No problem if the action is empty and i have a *pruebaSuccess.php* file.

Any idea?

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial has no HTML `<head>` tag into which symfony would insert the CSS file references, so they are not added.

If you want to render the result of an action without using the default layout, consider using  a standard template and turning all CSS off apart from the file you need:

*apps/frontend/modules/miembros/config/view.yml:*

```
fooSuccess:
  stylesheets: [-*, my_css_file.css]
```

`-*` removes all other CSS files in syfmony's configuration cascade.